# Javascript Click on Element

Tags: javascript, click, element

I am new and trying to use Javascript to click on Element with below attributes.

```
button[data-bind="visible: showProcessNow(), contextedId: 'process-now', click: processNow.bind($data), text: resx.onlineStore.PlaceMyOrder"]
button[class="process-now"]
button[id="process-now-667"]
```

I have tried belows but it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('process-now')[0].click();

document.querySelector('.process-now').click();
```

Can someone help me to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: `It doesn't work`: what *does* happen? Is there an error in you dev tools console?

Comment: The button was not clicked as expected. No error msg :(

Comment: What happens if you simply log the element(s) retrieved with `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelector`? Are those elements found?

Comment: I actually only use automa tool to create a work flow on the page. Since this specific button I couldn't "click" it by the tool, I start to look for javascript to do it. I am brand new for the javascript :) But I will try whether I can check the value from document.getElementsByClassName or document.querySelector.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can reproduce the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

you should move the script tag to the end of the body tag. because it tries to run the script before elements render.

consider that I don't mean that scripts in the head tag are wrong completely but you don't what to create a function and run that function after HTML elements are rendered.

```
<html>
<head>
<script></script> // wrong place
</head>
<body>
...
<script></script> // right place
</body>
</html>
```